# How do I create a 2 task for same function using Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, delay, raspberry-pi3

I'm playing around with Qt. I am using one ultrasonic sensor, If I start the toy it works fine.

Currently, What am I doing? For example, I have programmed a toy, I will start the toy then it will start walking continuously, If someone is in front of the ultrasonic sensor, then it will sense that and will stop walking. (This is working fine). This is what I have created.

`Toystart Thread:`

```
bool Toystart::Limit()
{
    if(Dist <= 55)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

`main Thread:`

```
int sensor = 0;

if (toystart->Limit() )
{
    if(sensor == 0)
      {  
           toystart->Stop_talking();
           delay (5000);

           sensor = 1;
           break;
      }
}
```

What do I want exactly?

The above-mentioned code working fine, I want to create a more function. For example some person in front of doll that stops talking 5 seconds then it will check again the still Obst there it will stop talking. It needs to check again after 5 seconds if still Obst there It will go to new function there it will say please leave me then after 5 seconds if Obst not there it will walk.

Comment: So difficult to understand what you want. Can you please edit the question to specify clearly what you want ?

Comment: @ Vishaal Shankar Thanks for your support. Sorry for the inconvenience, I am not familiar in English. I have edited. Here I have updated what I am doing now and what I want? Still, if you have confusion please comment the doubt exactly.

Comment: @Geevan I think the problem is not English, but how to explain your problem simply and clearly. For example, in this case, you need to describe the problem in Qt code without the sensor API. Focus on the tile "create 2 tasks(QThread) to do the same function(Work)" which implemented via Qt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But it is a blocking call. Your function is stuck for 5 seconds, and depending on how delay() is implemented it might make your whole app unresponsive to any other calls and events.

Pseudocode:

```
if (obstacle is near) {
  if (last_operation == "wait") {
    last_operation = "Action";
    takeAction();
  } else {
    last_operation = "wait";
    wait();
  }
} else { // no obstacle
  last_operation = "go";
  go();
}
```

Is that what you're looking after?

Comment: I think this way I can try, but not exactly this.